# FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument

Tags: debian, x-server, qt, hdmi

I am trying to solve a problem with my video output via HDMI, a situation is as follow.

I have device (BeagleBone Black) which runs on Debian Jessie 8.2, I developed an application in Qt5 which embeds MPlayer in QMainWindow. When I launch that application it doesn't show video playback inside that application's window (It works well on my Ubuntu VM). I figured out that I have error which repeats all the time in my **/var/log/Xorg.0.log** -> "*FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument*". I am not sure where is the problem, as video reproduction also works when I run it in vnc client, something with hdmi? video drivers? or Qt platform I use to run my application?

Comment: I guess you already search on stackoverflow etc. But maybe this is still a useful link, even if the problem is not solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265548/fbdev0-fbioputcmap-invalid-argument-error-in-xorg-0-log-file

Comment: Is your VM using the same video driver (fbdev)?

Comment: @L.Levrel No, I don't have xorg.conf file in my /etc/X11 directory.

Comment: You don't need an `xorg.conf` file, the X server has some built-in "options". Have a look into `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`: you'll find bunches of lines prefixed with the driver name, like `FBDEV(0):` or `VESA(0):` or...